# How interpret HTML tag in Symfony console?

Tags: php, symfony, console-application

On a project I have to create a command that displays a table in Symfony console based on a CSV file.

In this CSV file there is a description with HTML tag like : I love < br/> sushi. I would like the console interpret tags.

EDIT:

I misspoke, I would like HTML tag to be intrepret in console
from
[image]

to

[image]

Comment: This `br2nl` function might be of use - https://www.ask-sheldon.com/br2nl/

Comment: It's only work for <br> no ? I am looking for something general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using https://www.ask-sheldon.com/br2nl/ as a base you could use...

```
function br2nl($string) {
    return preg_replace('/\<(\s*)?br(\s*)?\/?\>/i', "\n", $string);
}
```

This will convert all br tags (with >=0 spaces on either side of the br and with/without the closing clash) to a new line:

```
<br>
< br>
<br >
<br/>
< br/>
<br />
<    br/>
<br    />
<  br  />
```

See
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e0cc0a2ba2a41ad901ffeb71dce0a79329053d98